# how stay in the current page after update a row with datables plugins and laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

in this case , when I selected the 2+th page (for exemple the 5th page ) and update a row , the table return me to the first page , I dont get what happen , I used [image]

and

[image]

but the problem stay ,,, any idea please , thanks

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image.

Comment: ok I will update it

Comment: Are you calling your function via JavaScript?. You can use e.preventDefault().... this will make the new upgrades without reloading the page

Comment: thanks @Kirasiris , I did it but nothing change , this problem Tired me very much